# Using Spreadsheet Sequence as an Attribute?

Tags: geometry-nodes

is there any idea to use or turn the vertices sequence in spreadsheet to attribute that can be used in geometry node ?

[image]

Comment: The input nodes can get these for you: Index node the the integer index of the vertex (0-15 there), or Position node to the the (x,y,z) coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is only there so that the question can be marked as closed:*.

The Node `Index` returns the current number of the element of a domain (*Vertex, Edge, Face, Face Corner, etc.*)

[image]